# Why is the usage of $this in PHP necessary when referencing methods or variables in the same class?

Tags: php, oop, this

I was explaining to a Java developer why his method call wasn't working. He just needed to add `$this->method_name();`

He then asked me, *"Why do I need to add **$this** to the method when it's declared in the same class?"*

I didn't really know how to answer. Maybe it's because PHP has a global namespace and it you need to explicitly tell it that the method you are looking for belongs to the current class? But then why doesn't PHP check the current class for the method BEFORE looking at the global namespace?

Comment: I just would say: PHP is not Java.

Comment: I actually prefer this, self, etc even in languages where it's not required. It makes it clear exactly what you're referencing.

Comment: Agreed, you're less likely to get a result you didn't want.

Comment: I have to say, when using pointers in C++ I go so far as to use `this` just for clarity reasons. It may be because I used PHP for years before doing much OOP C++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem would also be that if you declared a `function foo()` and a method `foo()`, php would have a hard time figuring out which you meant - consider this example:

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    echo 'blah';
}

class bar
{
    function foo()
    {
         echo 'bleh';
    }
    function bar()
    {
         // Here, foo() would be ambigious if $this-> wasn't needed.
    }
}
?>
```

So basically you can say that PHP - because of its "non-100%-object-orientedness" (meaning that you can also have functions outside classes) - has this "feature" :)

Comment: Ah Yes! This makes complete sense!

Answer (score 4):

If I have to guess: Because it was easier than the alternatives. Object oriented support in PHP has always been very much of a hack. I vaguely remember reading a discussion about the upcoming closure support that will appear in PHP 5.3. Appearently it was really, really hard to implement lexical closures in PHP due to it's scoping rules. Probably because you can nest a class in a function in another class and stuff like that. All that freedom possibly makes stuff like this incredibly hard.

Answer (score 3):

This is not unusual. Python, Javascript, Perl (and others) all make you refer to a `this` or `self` when dealing with objects.

Answer (score 1):

That's just how scope works in PHP. `$obj->f()` refers to `$foo` in the function scope. If you want to get the class property `$obj->foo` within `f()`, it's `$this->foo`.

```
global $foo;
$foo = 99;

class myclass
{
    public $foo;

    function f()
    {
        $this->foo = 12;
        $foo = 7;

        // $this->foo != $foo != $GLOBALS['foo']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$this refers to the calling object. The [PHP docs](http://jm.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) have good examples and further details.

Comment: the 'called' object, you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Seems PHP hasn't been properly OOPed.  In Java and C++, references to the current object ('this') are implicit, ie no explicit mention is needed, leaving the code much cleaner.
Perhaps there is some reason this is difficult with PHP implementation ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).