# Usage of this in C++, PHP, other languages

Tags: php, c++, this, dynamic-typing, static-typing

Why can internal class variables in C++ use `this`, but do not have to, while internal PHP class properties *must* use `$this->`?

Example C++ (can use `this`, but doesn't have to)

```
void setHealth(int h)
{
    health = h;
}
```

Example PHP (must use `$this->`)

```
public function setHealth($h)
{
    $this->health = $h;
}
```

Are there any pros/cons to requiring `$this->` in PHP?  I can see that it clarifies beyond doubt that the variable does belong to this particular class instance opposed to possibly being a local scoped variable, but C++ manages just fine without this requirement  . . .

Comment: In C++ `this` is a pointer to class, so if you define class and `setHealth` as method of this class you can use `this->health = h;`, but this can be skiped

Comment: BTW, Perl, Python, Javascript and may be some other *scripting* languages also has the requirement to use `this` (or `self`). I think it was made for parser speed.

Comment: This has been addressed to some extent here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912312/why-is-the-usage-of-this-in-php-necessary-when-referencing-methods-or-variables

Comment: Even some C++ programmers use the `var_` notation for member variables. It makes the code easier to read (for humans, that is, the compiler doesn't care).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ has static typing and requires declarations. The compiler can easily figure out what the name (`health`) refers to.

In PHP, OTOH, `$health = $h;` would be ambiguous. Is that a local variable or class member variable? Remember, you can add properties to objects on the fly, so checking what properties the class declares is not enough.